# Xcode Preview not showing

Tags: ios, swift

I was following a YouTube tutorial about how to connect my django backend to Swift and when I finished following along, I just get a blank grey area where the phone preview should be. Anyone know why this would happen? Here's my Model file and my View.

```
import Foundation

struct Account: Codable, Hashable {
    var email: String
    var username: String
    var first_name: String
    var last_name: String
    var is_venue: Bool
    var date_joined: Date
    var last_login: Date
    var is_active: Bool
    var is_admin: Bool
    var is_superuser: Bool
}
```

And View

```
import SwiftUI
struct AccountView: View {
@State var accounts = [Account]()

var body: some View {
    ForEach(accounts, id: \.self) {item in
    HStack {
        Text(item.first_name)
    }
    }.onAppear(perform: loadAccount)
}
func loadAccount() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/account/") // URL is the endpoint of API
    else {
        print("API is down")
        return
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("Basic amZsb3JlbmNlMEBnbWFpbC5jb206QmEka2V0YmExMUZsMEppbW15ITEh", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Account].self, from: data) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.accounts = response
                }
                return
            }
        }
        
    }.resume()
}
}

struct AccountView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AccountView()
}
}
```

Comment: Does it run on simulator ? Also did you start the preview (data being downloaded, account array is empty by default)

Comment: In AccountView_Previews you have AccountView() and that will construct an AccountView with accounts = [] and then your view is a ForEach of the emptyArray so there's no actual stuff to preview

Comment: Nothing shows when I run the simulator, the build is now failing. I'm just confused because this how the tutorial was written, and his worked lol. I'll find another one, thanks for your help guys

Comment: Another thing : your ForEach is not included in a VStack or other structure.